# COVID-19 - should I cancel our trip to Japan?

Tags: japan, event-based-effects, covid-19

We planned a 3-week trip to Japan in March, but because of the recent increase in infections over there, we started to wonder if it wouldn't be smarter to cancel.

This is our travel plan:

- 06-03-2020: Munich -> London -> Tokyo
- 27-03-2020: Tokyo -> London -> Munich

We are mainly worried about two possibilities:

1. The airports shutting down, preventing us from getting back (my boss wouldn't be too happy).
2. Ending up in quarantine because we have an infected person on the plane.

While there, we planned on staying mainly in the countryside anyways, so the risk of getting infected ourselves is rather low in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think this question is possible to answer objectively. You need to make your own judgement. You should ensure you have travel insurance covering these possibilities.

Comment: @MJeffryes Choose your insurance carefully: many won't cover events like this.

Answer (score 3):

This question is likely to get closed as opinion-based, but a few reference points:

1. Unless things get positively apocalyptic, it is *exceedingly* unlikely that Japan's airports would shut down completely.  Flights might be reduced, but as a comparison point, airports in China -- even in Wuhan -- have kept operating throughout the crisis there.
2. On the inbound flight, this would require an infected person coming from Munich or London, which is statistically improbable.  On the way back, this is a higher possibility, but still unlikely unless (again) there's a major outbreak.

FWIW, I was in Tokyo last week, and while it's not exactly panic in the air, people are definitely taking precautions: temperature scans at the airport, more masks than usual, hand washing & sanitizers, large gatherings cancelled, etc .  This in itself seems likely to limit the spread of the virus, making full-blown contagion less likely.  But at the end of the day it's your call.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience - yeah, we will wait until the end of the week before we make our final decision.